# Single JSON to Fetch Multiple Records

Tags: android, json

I am using this tutorial : http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-multilevel-listview-tutorial/

here he created 3 different JSONs,

**First**, to fetch list of Albums

**Second**, to fetch list of Songs under Album

**Third**, to show single song Information

but i need a small change here, *instead to 3 different-different JSONs*, i **wanna use single JSON for both Albums & Songs**, and i have created my demo JSON as well, and i am **able to get list of Albums but not getting list of Songs**, my JSON look like this and i am using same code as he has written for Client Side :

**my.json:**

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "127 Hours",
    "album": "127 Hours",
    "songs": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Never Hear Surf Music Again",
            "duration": "5:52"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "The Canyon",
            "duration": "3:01"
        }
    ]
}
]
```

Logcat:

```
06-18 06:36:56.318: D/dalvikvm(793): GC_CONCURRENT freed 143K, 7% free 3745K/4012K, paused 6ms+127ms, total 243ms
06-18 06:36:56.399: I/Choreographer(793): Skipped 37 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-18 06:36:56.689: I/Choreographer(793): Skipped 66 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-18 06:36:57.508: D/Track List JSON:(793): [
06-18 06:36:57.508: D/Track List JSON:(793): {
06-18 06:36:57.508: D/Track List JSON:(793): "id":1,
06-18 06:36:57.508: D/Track List JSON:(793): "name":"127 Hours",
06-18 06:36:57.508: D/Track List JSON:(793): "album":"127 Hours",
06-18 06:36:57.508: D/Track List JSON:(793): "songs":[
06-18 06:36:57.508: D/Track List JSON:(793): {
06-18 06:36:57.508: D/Track List JSON:(793): "id":1,
06-18 06:36:57.508: D/Track List JSON:(793): "name":"Never Hear Surf Music Again",
06-18 06:36:57.508: D/Track List JSON:(793): "duration":"5:52"
06-18 06:36:57.508: D/Track List JSON:(793): },
06-18 06:36:57.508: D/Track List JSON:(793): {
06-18 06:36:57.508: D/Track List JSON:(793): "id":2,
06-18 06:36:57.508: D/Track List JSON:(793): "name":"The Canyon",
06-18 06:36:57.508: D/Track List JSON:(793): "duration":"3:01"
06-18 06:36:57.508: D/Track List JSON:(793): }
06-18 06:36:57.508: D/Track List JSON:(793): ]
06-18 06:36:57.508: D/Track List JSON:(793): }
06-18 06:36:57.508: D/Track List JSON:(793): ]
06-18 06:36:57.668: W/System.err(793): org.json.JSONException: Value [{"id":1,"songs":[{"id":1,"duration":"5:52","name":"Never Hear Surf Music Again"},{"id":2,"duration":"3:01","name":"The Canyon"}],"album":"127 Hours","name":"127 Hours"}] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject
06-18 06:36:57.668: W/System.err(793):  at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
06-18 06:36:57.668: W/System.err(793):  at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:158)
06-18 06:36:57.788: W/System.err(793):  at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:171)
06-18 06:36:57.888: W/System.err(793):  at com.example.androidhive.TrackListActivity$LoadTracks.doInBackground(TrackListActivity.java:155)
06-18 06:36:57.898: W/System.err(793):  at com.example.androidhive.TrackListActivity$LoadTracks.doInBackground(TrackListActivity.java:1)
06-18 06:36:57.898: W/System.err(793):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
06-18 06:36:57.898: W/System.err(793):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
06-18 06:36:57.898: W/System.err(793):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
06-18 06:36:57.898: W/System.err(793):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
06-18 06:36:57.909: W/System.err(793):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

**Note: I am able to fetch List of Albums, but whenever i do click on any of the Album not getting Songs**

Comment: You can find many json browser viewers online, I use them a lot when using json files: 

http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/

Comment: Which is the problem? Post code and logcat!

Comment: it seems your json is valid - check at http://jsonlint.com/ can u post your code ?

Comment: can you find solution maybe here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/JsonReader.html ?

Comment: you want to parse the json ?

Answer (score 0):

Since your json data starts with square brace means its a jsonarray and you need to parse it start with jsonarray.

This code may help you..

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray("Your_json_string");
 for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++){
     System.out.println("id:"+array.getJSONObject(i).getString("id"));
     System.out.println("name:"+array.getJSONObject(i).getString("name"));
     System.out.println("album:"+array.getJSONObject(i).getString("album"));
     JSONArray innerArray = getJSONObject(i)..getJSONArray("songs");
      for(int k=0;k<innerArray.length();k++){
        JsonObject innerObj = innerArray.getJSONObject(k);
         System.out.println("id:"+innerObj.getString("id"));
         System.out.println("Name:"+innerObj.getString("name"));
          System.out.println("duration:"+innerObj.getString("duration"));          

      }
    }
```

Comment: is he asking for parsing json data?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to convert a JSON array to a JSON object, that's the problem.

```
org.json.JSONException: Value [.......] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Here:

```
JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(json);
```

Your JSON string is actually an array, not an object, because it starts with `[]`.

If you want to deal with an object change it and make it starts with `{}`, and you're done (or convert it to a JSONArray and get the firts value)!

---

Edit:

this should work:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "127 Hours",
    "album": "127 Hours",
    "songs": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Never Hear Surf Music Again",
            "duration": "5:52"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "The Canyon",
            "duration": "3:01"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: please show me how my JSON should look like, because i don't want to do changes in my Code

Comment: Please, update the question adding your code and new logcat and explaining what is not working. :)